# Error in javascript: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run my code below then it shows error `object is not a function` in console. This error  is on this line `var todo = new Todo('contents');` in my `script.js` file. How can I make it work?

Here is my todo.js file

```
var Todo = (function(c) {
var contents = $('.' + c);

var showel = function (d) {
    contents.prepend(d);
},

add = function (name) {
    if(name != "") {
        var div = $('<div class="names"></div>')
        .append('<span>' + name + '</span>')
        .append("<button class='update' class='update'>Edit</button>")
        .append("<button class='remove' name='remove'>Remove</button>");
    }

    return showel(div);
},

addUpdateField = function (dom) {
    var name = dom.parent().find('span').text(),
        field = $('<input type="text" value="' + name + '" />'),
        update = $('<button class="updateBtn">Update</button>');
    dom.parent().html('').append(field).append(update);

    return;
},

update = function(el) {
    var val = el.parent().find('input').val();
    el.parent().html('<span>' + val + '</span>')
    .append('<button class="update" class="update">Edit</button>')
    .append('<button class="remove" class="remove">Remove</button>');

    return;
},

remove = function (el) {
    return el.remove();
};

return {
    add             : add,
    update          : update,
    remove          : remove,
    addUpdateField  : addUpdateField
};
})();
```

here is my script.js file

```
$(function () {
var todo = new Todo('contents');

$('.addBtn').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').val();
    todo.add(name);
});

$('.contents').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var el = $(this).parent();
    todo.remove(el);
});

$('.contents').on('click', '.update', function() {
    var dom = $(this);
    todo.addUpdateField(dom);
});

$('.contents').on('click', '.updateBtn', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    todo.update(el);
});

});
```

**here is html code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="name" name="name" />
    <input type="button" class="addBtn" name="add" value="Add" />
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should change the ASEF to a normal function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are immediately executing the function that is assigned to `Todo`. That function returns an object, so `Todo` refers to the returned object, not a function (hence the "Not a function" error).

I assume you intended something along the lines of this:

```
var Todo = function () {

    this.add = function () { //Note the use of `this` here
        //Do stuff
    };
    //etc...

}; //No self-invoking parentheses here
```

Now, `Todo` refers to a constructor function which you can invoke with the `new` operator, as you are currently trying to do.

Also note that this pattern will result in every instance of `Todo` having a separate copy of each method, which isn't very efficient. It would be better to declare the methods as properties of the `prototype`:

```
var Todo = function () {
    //Initialize the Todo instance
};
Todo.prototype.add = function () {
    //Do stuff
};
```

Now, all instance of `Todo` will share a single copy of the methods.

Comment: It works like this. But I wanted to modify my code so that it should work the way I am trying to do in my example above. How can I modify my code so that it works.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve... what's wrong with changing it to be like this?

Comment: I am trying yo achieve this way http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/

Comment: That article is describing how to namespace functions... it's not describing constructor functions, which is what you need here. The examples in that article would not be called with `new`. Also, maybe you should heed the warning at the top of the article... "This article is obsolete".