# Prototype is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, prototype

Im using the following code in order to learn JS prototype and how to works with objects,(after I read about it on the net Im new to JS...)I want to create a root  object that  other class can use and extend 
not sure if I do that right...currently I've error at the sound (Cannot set property 'sound' of undefined),any idea what Im doing wrong or maybe there is better way to write it,(for me it's the third draft...:) )

```
var obj = function(name){

    this.name  = name;
};

obj.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}

var person = new obj("Bill");

console.log(person.getName());


var animal = new obj();

animal.prototype.sound = function(sound){
    console.log(sound)
}


var dog = new animal();


dog.sound("wof");
```

Comment: I got error of Cannot set property 'sound' of undefined in the last  statment...

Comment: Even if there is a better way to do it, I'm interested to hear why this approach isn't working.

Comment: @DeeMac- not sure way Im fairly new to this topic so currently I got and error when I run this file ...

Comment: Ok updated my answer - this has to do with object inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new obj();` returns an object not a function, so when you call

```
var animal = new obj();
```

The `animal` variable will be filled with an object which is NOT function. This statement

```
var dog = new animal();
```

returns `undefined` because animal is not a function (constructor function). Note that operator `new` is used for functions only not for literal objects

For more info on this topic please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951550/error-in-javascript-object-is-not-a-function)

---

### A simple JavaScript inheritance pattern

At first define a base class (there is no class concept in JS but I use it for more convenience)

```
function Obj(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Obj.prototype.setName = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Next, you can define an `animal` class which is extending `obj` class.

```
function Animal(name, legs){ 
    // This is its own property
    this.legs = legs;
    // This is accessible via prototype chain
    this.setName(name);
}

// link this class to the obj class
Animal.prototype = new Obj();
```

A visualized schema for this pattern would be:

```
    Animal
  +------------+  
  | legs       |           Obj
  | __proto__  | -----> +-----------+  
  +------------+        | name      |         prototype object for Obj
                        | __proto__ | -------> +--------------------+  
                        +-----------+          | setName function   |  
                                               +--------------------+
```

**UPDATE #1**
To declare another class, `Person` for example, you might want to do this:

```
function Person(name, addr, phoneNo){
    this.name = name;  // This is inherited from the Obj class
    this.addr = addr;  // Its own property
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo; // Its own propert
    this.legs = 2; // This is from Animal 
}

Person.prototype = new Animal();
```

Comment: I don't believe it's `var dog = new animal();` which is giving him the problem though!?

Comment: @abforce - so how should i contract it better ?

Comment: @Billgoldberg Are you looking for a way to simulate inheritance in JS?

Comment: Thanks voted up,one last question is now should extend it to person with for example firstName lastName legs,workingAt,address,etc...

Comment: @downvoter why downvote? if something is wrong please let me know

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because sound is undefined - the property does not exist.

An simple way to create an object with a sound property is simply like this (uses jquery):

```
var animal = { walk: function(){ return 'animal is walking'; }, legs: 4  }

var dog = $.extend({ sound: '' }, animal); 

dog.sound = 'woof';
```

The reason why your example wont work is because you have instantiated a new instance of obj - which does not have a sound property. So you need a mechanism to extend the object you have instantiated. So in my example I am showing you a quick and easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make an inheritance

You have to do

```
var animal = function () {}
animal.prototype = new obj();
animal.prototype.constructor=animal;
```

src: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

In an other way you may want to know that you can use:

```
obj.prototype.__defineGetter__("name", function () { return this.n; /* where n is the name */ });
```

and use it like that

```
var a = new obj("foo");
console.log(a.name);
```

Comment: Thanks but not sure how to put this code what is the var animal = function () {} ?

Comment: it's just to create the class animal